# Fetching a value from database in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to fetch some values from the database and I'm getting this error

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined index: name
>   Filename: views/pro_view.php
>   Line Number: 12

**My controller:**

```
$this->load->model('profile_model');

$data['profile_data'] = $this->profile_model->get_records();

$this->load->view('pro_view', $data);
```

Model:

```
function get_records()
{
    $r = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $query = $this->db->get_where('profile', array('id' => $r));
    return $query->result();
}
```

View:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $profile_data["name"]  ?>" />
```

if I `var_dump(($profile_data);` I'm getting everything in an array.

I read other similar questions and their answers, no luck.

Comment: By default CI return as a object and you need to echo like this in view for every value which you want to print $profile_data[0]->name

Comment: this is just what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to fetch single row then use

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('profile', array('id' => $r));
$ret = $query->row();
return $ret->name;
```

Controller

```
$data['name'] = $this->profile_model->get_records();

$this->load->view('pro_view', $data);
```

View

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>" />
```

And for your present code you need to use `foreach loop`

```
 foreach (profile_data as $row)
   { ?>
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $row->name;?>" />

  <?php }?>
```

**[result()](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html)**

> This method returns the query result as an array of objects, or an
>   empty array on failure. Typically you’ll use this in a foreach loop

Comment: i have like 20 type of values in row, you know like a normal profile. Name, phone, etc.

Comment: You need to use foreach loop as i post in my answer

Comment: i was getting an error. `$profile_data[0]->name` in the view worked for me.

Comment: @Saty error is because not accessing the value using the key index in and he is using function for single row

Comment: But using my code there is no change to get any error. I'm providing answer for both  fetch single row or fetching object from database!!!

Comment: yeah i agree with you but for now he is accessing only one row from database based on id and in this case only need to 

echo $profile_data[0]->name 

in view page

Answer (score 1):

**Controller**

```
    $this->load->model('profile_model');

    $data['profile_data'] = $this->profile_model->get_records();

    $this->load->view('pro_view', $data);
```

**Model**

```
$r = $this->uri->segment(3);
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('profile');
$this->db->where('id',$r);
$q = $this->db->get();
if($q->num_rows() > 0){
$row = $q->row();
return $row->name;
}
return false;
```

**view**

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>" />
```